# How to get a method to work in all forms in my project in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, methods

I wrote code(connection string) to open sql database in form1  then i need to open the same database in form2 .
so i think to write method to do this ?
How to get this method to work in all forms in my project in c#, where i neet to plse it to work in all project forms????
plz help

Comment: Please not short forms of word, and of course there is a first question: **What did you try?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a base class for your forms that has all the shared functionality and inherit your forms from it.

Comment: iam new in  c#..... how to do that???

Comment: @E.S Maybe you should read a book about programming or look for online resources to learn more about programming.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

Comment: Why would a base class for forms be a good place for database functionality?    Consider a separate class instead, as codingbiz suggests.

Comment: @Andomar - I think it would be an OK place for placing access to a connection string.

Comment: @Oded: I've seen a few base classes for forms that evolved into a 5,000 line monolith with all application logic.  Better to avoid this right from the start.

Answer (score 2):

You can put those functionality in a separate class and call them from your forms

```
public class MyDBService
{

   public static DataTable GetEmployees()
   {
      //Connect to DB
      //return Employees
   }

   public static DataTable GetDepartments()
   {
      //Connect to DB
      //return Departments
   }


   public static DataTable GetLocations()
   {
      //Connect to DB
      //return Locations
   }

}
```

Then in each of your form you can have

```
var employees = MyDBService.GetEmployees();
var depts = MyDBService.GetDepartments();
```

Thus separating your data access from your UI/Presentation

You can also look into

- [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)
- [Active Record Pattern](https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=active%20record%20pattern&oq=active%20record%20pattern&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) etc
- 3-tier design/application

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class MyClass
{

public static string GetConnection()
{
//Write Code

}

public static void Methods()
{

//Write Code
}


}
```

/// How to use this calss

//in your .cs or .vb file of form

```
string con=MyClass.GetConnection();
MyClass.Method2();
```